# Does TensorFlow plan to support OpenCL?

Tags: tensorflow, opencl

I am under the impression that TF only supports CUDA. From my research, the only way to get it to support OpenCL and AMD GPUs is to get a separate "adapter" module such as [TF Coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander) and suffer through the performance failure:

[image: Performance Chart]

From the GitHub:

> for the recurrent networks, Coriander is around 4 times slower than using NVIDIA® CUDA™ directly.

The module does seem to be under near constant development, checking the insights tab, but I'm not sure how optimistic to be. So should I be optimistic about this and expect a near-native experience in under a few years? If not, is support being planned for an *actually* native solution? If they aren't will AMD's upcoming 7nm architecture change the dev's minds?

I realize this may be a little off-topic. If it is, please tell me if I can put anywhere else.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the Tensorflow folks?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good suggestion, how do I go about that?

Comment: Here are some of the things they're thinking about: https://www.tensorflow.org/community/roadmap

Comment: I think that you can use HIP to convert Cuda code to "generic C++" which can then be compiled to OpenCL (which will then run on AMD ROCm systems). Never tried it. See https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP

Answer (score 16):

As part of contrib, you can build Tensorflow with SYCL support.

SYCL is "single source OpenCL", a new standard from Khronos that allows one to write high level C++ code that can be compiled to run on OpenCL devices.

The folks at CodePlay software have been heavily involved in it, and you can see one their blogposts on the topic [here](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/tensorflow%E2%84%A2-for-opencl%E2%84%A2-using-sycl%E2%84%A2).

So in short, you're not going to get a pip package of it, you'll need to build it yourself.  And the performance might not be as good, since the project is still early days.

You can find a tutorial on how to get started [here](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/tensorflow-guide/tensorflow-native-compilation).  Bear in mind, this uses CodePlay's propitiatory version of SYCL, but maybe you can get it working with an open implementation such as triSYCL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This does still seem to have some of the same issues as Coriander and seems to not be much better. Should I just wait it out for native integration from AMD and/or CodePlay?

Comment: I'm not too sure of the issues RE Coriander, would you be able to elaborate please?  One thing that can be said for the SYCL approach is that it "officially" part of the main Tensorflow repo.  No package support yet, but there is that implicit endorsement.

Comment: Coriander is the module I mentioned in my question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's on me sorry, I should've checked your question again.  Good luck with your setup, I watch the relatively quiet SYCL and OpenCL tags if you have any further questions

Comment: The project seems to have died in 2018. Is there any alternative?